# Google Cloud Platform - Connecting to Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I am trying to access Elastic Search via my static IP address but it's not working.

***What did I try?***

1. I created a Bitnami Elastic Search VM Instance from GCP Marketplace
2. I assigned a static IP to the same VM
3. I replaced the `network.host` to 0.0.0.0 inside *elasticsearch.yml* file
4. I added my static IP to `network.publish_host` inside *elasticsearch.yml* file
5. I added a firewall rule to allow all ports and added 0.0.0.0 as source filter

Now when trying to access Elastic Search using http://_my_static_ip:9200 I get nothing, the request fails. What am I missing here?? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: r u able to test it using `curl localhost:9200` ?

Comment: Hi, yes, localhost works fine. I think I am not configuring the firewall rules or something incorrectly

Comment: I don't have a GCP account but these setting works fine for aws , let me know if you want to test it on AWS

Comment: Hi, thanks, I have fixed the issue. Someone on Fiverr helper me. I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was my GCP being using an IPv6 address, I didn't know about this, this is something a developer on Fiverr told me, anyone having the same issue with Bitnami's GCP deployment needs to add the following line:

`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

to the following file:

`/opt/bitnami/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options`

After that restart your elasticsearc service using the following command:

`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart`

That should fix the issue if you have proper firewall rules set up and also added proper IPs to `elasticsearch.yml` config file. Read original question's ***What did I try?*** section.

Comment: Please provide more details about "my GCP being using an IPv6 address". As I can see in the documentation https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#specifications "VPC networks only support IPv4 unicast traffic. They do not support broadcast, multicast, or IPv6 traffic within the network; VMs in the VPC network can only send to IPv4 destinations and only receive traffic from IPv4 sources. However, it is possible to create an IPv6 address for a global load balancer."

Comment: Hi @SerhiiRohoza That's what a Fiverr user told me and adding that line solves the issue. I am not good with GCP or VMs but that line fixed my issue.